# PreparedStatement error: Parameter 12 undefined

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have eleven fields which I want to insert in the database. The error that shows is that my 12 parameter is undefined which is ps.executeUpdate(). What should I do?

My insert method is as follows.

```
public void update(User user){
        try{
        Connection conn = DbUtils.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE db.db set id = ?,username = ?,password = ?,firstname = ?, lastname = ?, fathersname =?, gender = ?, email = ?,address =? , phnno = ?, courses = ?" + "WHERE id =?");
        ps.setInt(1, user.getId());
        ps.setString(2, user.getName());
        ps.setString(3, user.getPwd());
        ps.setString(4, user.getFname());
        ps.setString(5,  user.getLname());
        ps.setString(6, user.getFathername());
        ps.setString(7, user.getAddress());
        ps.setString(8, user.getEmail());
        ps.setString(9, user.getGender());
        ps.setString(10, user.getPhno());
        ps.setString(11, user.getCradio());
        ps.execute();           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    `
```

Comment: You have 12 placeholders in your query and you only provide 11. Do the math.

Comment: And there should be a *space* between 11th placeholder and `WEHRE`. Shoule be `...courses = ? WHERE id =?"`

Comment: BTW: Why are you updating `id` of the user? Is it not unique? And your query is going to fail, unless you have a handle to *old id* value. If this was not your intention, then remove the `id=?,` from your query, re-number the parameter numbers, and `setXXX` for `where id=?`

Answer (score 0):

Function should have another parameter for 12 placeholder.
Like this:

```
public void update(User user){
        try{
        Connection conn = DbUtils.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE db.db set id = ?,username = ?,password = ?,firstname = ?, lastname = ?, fathersname =?, gender = ?, email = ?,address =? , phnno = ?, courses = ?" + " WHERE id =?");
        ps.setInt(1, user.getId());
        ps.setString(2, user.getName());
        ps.setString(3, user.getPwd());
        ps.setString(4, user.getFname());
        ps.setString(5,  user.getLname());
        ps.setString(6, user.getFathername());
        ps.setString(7, user.getAddress());
        ps.setString(8, user.getEmail());
        ps.setString(9, user.getGender());
        ps.setString(10, user.getPhno());
        ps.setString(11, user.getCradio());
        ps.setInt(12, user.getId()); //parameter 12 added
        ps.execute();           
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

Do you really want to update ID field as well?